# Can you bring back the "show full cell content" bar (UI element) in new Excel 2007+ ribbon?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2003, there was an UI element below menu, which showed full content of a cell where cursor was.

If a field contained a long string which would not fit into the column and would not overflow to field on the right, it would be possible to move by keyboard the cursor to that field and the top "view-whole-cell" bar would show the full string.

Where in Excel 2007+ ribbon options can I bring this or did Microsoft remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still there:

- Click the double down arrow on the right of the formula bar (just below the ribbon).
- Drag the horizontal splitter to make it as large as you want.

[image]

If you're not seeing the formula bar at all, you can enable it here:

- Ribbon button
- Excel Options
- Advanced
- Enable "Show formula Bar" in the Display section.