# Show full contents of cell value, not formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/386728/315715) asks how to show long cell values when they are too long to be viewed in-place.

But it's a shame that when the cell value is the result of a formula, this box shows the formula and not the value:
[image: Long text not shown]

Is there a way I can see the *result* of the `CONCAT` and not the formula?

Comment: No, there is no way for that.

Comment: @MátéJuhász there is but not as described. go to formula tab click on evaluate formula and the click on evaluation. But its a function meant for something else

Comment: You could always copy and paste the value into another cell, using vba in a Worksheet_Calculate event.  Or instead of a formula you could use vba in a Worksheet_Change event to do the concatenation when either cell changes.  But it is not possible with formulas.

Comment: My best option so far seems to be to copy/paste the cell into Notepad. :S

Comment: This isn't exactly what you asked for, but if you really need this you might use  something to popup the value     Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox (ActiveCell.Value)
End Sub

Comment: @datatoo I actually quite like that solution. Write it up and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is *no*.  The Formula Bar displays the formula and the cell displays the value.

The best you can do is to format the cell, say **A2**, with **wrap** on and set the column width and row height to give you a reasonable display.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but if you really need this you might use something to popup the value 
The comment I left doesn't appear complete so here is one approach using a Userform you could call on a double-click and as the comment shows a MsgBox

```
Sub ViewListOfOpenWorkBooksAndWorkSheets()
Dim book As Workbook, sheet As Worksheet
  For Each book In Workbooks
   For Each sheet In book.Worksheets
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem book.Name + "!" + sheet.Name
   Next sheet
  Next book
 UserForm1.Show
 End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean) 
MsgBox (ActiveCell.Value)  
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an older thread, but I figured out a way on accident because of the programs I'm exporting as .csv and then importing into another program.  If you 'save as' your file with the formulas as a .csv file and then close out of the file, when you open it again the formulas seem to resolve and you see your text.  I then save the file back to .xlsx and good to go.  Weird work around, but it does work.

Comment: With that "workaround" you lose formulas and also all formatting from the workbook.